# Ballerina: Mutually exclusive table type errors

Tags: ballerina

In Swan Lake beta 2, I am trying to write a function which will accept a table of unknown type and return a row from it.

Minimal function body needed to trigger errors:

```
if (tb.length() == 0) {
  return ();
}
foreach var k in tb.keys() {
}
return ();
```

My problem is with declaring the method signature. Originally I tried:

```
public function myFunction(table<any> key<any> tb) returns any {
```

But when I added the call to `length()`, I got this error:

```
incompatible types: expected 'table<map<(any|error)>>', found 'table<any> key<any>'
```

So I changed the declaration to:

```
public function myFunction(table<map<(any|error)>> tb) returns any {
```

and all was well for a moment. But then I added the call to `keys()` and started getting this error for that line:

```
incompatible types: expected 'table<map<(any|error)>> key<anydata>', found 'table<map<(any|error)>> key<anydata>'
```

So I changed the declaration again:

```
public function myFunction(table<map<(any|error)>> key<anydata> tb) returns any {
```

But that resulted in a new error pointing to the declaration line:

```
table with constraint of type map cannot have key specifier or key type constraint
```

So there's no legal way to define the table!

Does anyone know how to thread this needle?

Comment: Try this for now. `myFunction(table<record {}> key<anydata> tb) returns any`.  `record{} is equivalent to map<anydata>`. This way, you will only be able to store `anydata` values. We will get back to you with a proper explanation soon.

Comment: Thank you! That worked and I was able to fill in the rest of my function without errors. If you want to make that comment an answer, I'll be happy to mark it correct.

Comment: The first issue is a bug reported here https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/32049